# Is it recomment to install ruby dependencies into local folder?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm learning ruby recently and I'm a front-end developer, I found the dependecies are installed to `C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0` folder when I use `bundle install`. it seems dependencies are installed globally by default like the `npm install -g`. I know that `Bundler` also have a way to install the gems to the local folder,  so I wonder is
it recommend to install the dependencies to the local folder like `npm` does?

Comment: Imagine you have multiple applications on your machine that have similar or the same dependencies. What would be the benefit of installing the same dependency multiple times instead of just once?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Composer, Bundler takes care of maintaining your dependencies, but rather than installing everything in the project folder, it distributes your gems system-wide, which are then shared by all of your projects. Using the Gemfile in your project folder, it keeps track of which libraries each project needs. Bundler is the default package manager for Rails, so you should simply let it do its thing. It does it quite well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer, actuallay i'm a iOS developer and front-end developer, all the package manager I used before like Cocoapods and npm both install dependencies in project folder, so I'm a little confused when I first use `Bundler`, but now that I know it's best practice to install dependencies in system-wide in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

### Use a Version Manager for Ruby, and Bundler for Gem Version Management

There are occasionally reasons to install gems in from one another isolation, but most often you should use a Ruby version manager to manage your non-system Rubies and Bundler to handle multiple gem versions and locations. Avoid modifying your system Ruby or its gems whenever possible. Also, be aware that even using RVM gemsets (or similar features in other version managers) without tweaking some poorly documented features like `rvm gemset globalcache enable` can create a level of isolation that is likely unnecessary and can bloat disk usage dramatically.

### If You *Need* Gem Isolation...

That said, if you want to ensure you are isolating your gems or localizing them to your application and aren't using direnv's [Ruby layout](https://direnv.net/man/direnv-stdlib.1.html#codelayout-rubycode) to manage all the various environment variables involved, you can use Bundler's [BUNDLE_PATH environment variable](https://bundler.io/v2.3/man/bundle-config.1.html) to "vendor" your gems into the local application directory (these days usually under `vendor/bundle`). For deployments or containerization, you can also invoke [bundle-install](https://bundler.io/v2.3/man/bundle-install.1.html) with the `--deployment` or `--standalone` flags and a list of gem groups to install if you don't want to rely on the availability of Bundler itself after installing the gems.

This sort of thing might be useful for building containers or tarballs, but isn't really very useful for *development*. Don't do it unless you have a really strong reason.